# Delay for tcsh scripts

Tags: tcsh

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.  My login shell is tcsh.  Whenever I run
a script in this shell, there is about a half-second delay before
it executes.  Suppose I make an empty file, tmp, in my home
directory, and make it executable (other scripts are similar).
If I enter "tmp" or "./tmp" or "/bin/tcsh tmp" or "/bin/tcsh
./tmp" or "/usr/bin/tcsh tmp", I get the delay.  But if I enter 
"/bin/bash tmp" or "source tmp" I don't.  Making the file tmp
with only the line "#!/bin/tcsh" doesn't change anything.
But if tmp consists of the line "#!/bin/bash", then I don't 
get the delay, even if I run "/bin/tcsh tmp".  There must be a 
simple solution, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's in `/etc/csh.cshrc` and `~/.tcshrc` or `~/.cshrc`?

Comment: There is no file ~/.trcshrc, and ~/.cshrc contains about 10 aliases (Ls, Cp, etc), and some setting of the variable PATH.  The file /etc/csh.cshrc is copied below:      # /etc/csh.cshrc: system-wide .cshrc file for csh(1) and tcsh(1)

if ($?tcsh && $?prompt) then

 bindkey "\e[1~" beginning-of-line # Home
 bindkey "\e[7~" beginning-of-line # Home rxvt
 bindkey "\e[2~" overwrite-mode    # Ins
 bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char       # Delete
 bindkey "\e[4~" end-of-line       # End
 bindkey "\e[8~" end-of-line       # End rxvt

 set autoexpand
 set autolist
 set prompt = " "
endif

Comment: Ahhhh . . . if I move .cshrc to x.cshrc (to tcsh doesn't find it), then all the delays disappear!  So, it is something in that file.  I can now go through, removing stuff, until I find out what it is.  Thanks, waltinator.  I knew it had to be simple!  :)